# Is it possible to call methods in __init__ to set attributes?

Tags: python, class, oop, methods, init

I'm trying to write a class that contains calculations for measuring volatility (in Finance). The calculations compute realized variances for each day using intra-day high frequency data. However, the technicalities don't really matter. My question is more general, regarding OOP design in Python to be more specific.

The problem I'm experiencing is that the code below works. But from the moment I am adding/changing something, it does not work anymore. Therefore I suspect that there is something wrong within the design of my Class. The only thing I can think about myself is that you cannot set an attribute within _*init*_ using a method. The code is given below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

DAL = pd.read_pickle('../data/DAL_timeseries.pkl') # stock prices -> pd.Series with datetime index

class Volatility():

    ''' 
    Class that contains multiple calculations for realized variance/volatility:

        - Realized variance 

    '''

    def __init__(self, stock):
        self.stock = stock
        self.daily_prices = self.stock.resample("1D")
        self.bv = self.calculate_bv()

    def estimator_bv(self, one_day_prices):
        # used to calculate bipower variance 
        if (len(one_day_prices) > 0):
            returns = np.abs( np.diff(np.log(one_day_prices)) )
            return (np.pi / 2.0) * np.inner(returns[1:], returns[:-1])
        else: 
            return np.nan

    def calculate_bv(self):
        bv = self.daily_prices.apply(self.estimator_bv)
        return bv.rename("bv").dropna()

    def plot(self):
        plt.plot(self.bv)

vola = Volatility(DAL)
vola.plot()

---> returns nice plot
```

The code above works, but strangely, when I add something to the `plot()` method, e.g.:

```
def plot(self):
  plt.plot(self.bv, label="bv")
  plt.legend()
```

I get this error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Desktop/case_fe/code/volatility.py in 
     46 
     47 
---> 48 vola = Volatility(DAL)

~/Desktop/case_fe/code/volatility.py in __init__(self, stock)
     20         self.stock = stock
     21         self.daily_prices = self.stock.resample("1D")
---> 22         self.bv = self.calculate_bv()
     23 
     24     def estimator_bv(self, one_day_prices):

~/Desktop/case_fe/code/volatility.py in calculate_bv(self)
     40 
     41     def calculate_bv(self):
---> 42         return bv.rename("bv").dropna()
     43     def plot(self):
     44 

NameError: name 'bv' is not defined`
```

And when I delete the `plt.legend()` line it somehow works again as expected? This error does also hold if add different changes or new methods to my Class. It really confuses me and I think I'm missing something important.

ps: I'm new to writing OOP in python but tried to use the correct jargon

Comment: Your error message indicates that, contrary to the class definition you posted, `calculate_bv` does *not* define a local variable `bv` before trying to use it.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: yes.

Comment: We can see in the error traceback that the error is not coming from the line you added in `plot`, but rather from `calculate_bv`, which is missing its `bv = self.daily_prices.apply(self.estimator_bv)` line from the first working example.

Comment: The code in the error is not the code that you posted. Please fix

Comment: @0x5453 the line is indeed missing in the error traceback but it is not missing in my code. Could there be another reason why it disappears in the error traceback?

Comment: @gardangerous. One reason could be if you edited the file and forgot to save before you reran it

Comment: @MadPhysicist if you're referring to the same as @0x5453, I have now ran my code several times and I am totally sure that the line `bv = self.daily_prices.apply(self.estimator_bv)` is included in my code. Strangely enough it does indeed disappears in the error. But why? Not because I excluded it, because it is there for sure!

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks for your suggestions! But I am working in just only one file/script, so I don't see why saving the file could solve? Moreover, I did save it now but the problem is still the same. The assignment of `bv` is in the code, but not in the error...

Comment: @gardangerous Restart the console, see if you still get the error the same way.

Comment: @gardangerous Also make sure that you are looking at `~/Desktop/case_fe/code/volatility.py`.  I've had bugs before where I accidentally did a "Save As" and my future edits were happening in the wrong file.

Comment: @MadPhysicist @0x5453 Thanks guys I tried but both don't work out! If I add e.g. `print('test') ` line at the same place, this line is seen in the error but the `bv` assignment is again not (but it is in the code for sure). Then it must be the case something that something is wrong with the design of my code, isn't it?

Comment: @gardangerous Your design is fine.  I'm not sure what could cause that line to disappear but I suspect it's something with your editor or environment.  I'm curious if you will get the same result in a different interpreter (e.g. `python` instead of `ipython`) or if you paste your code into a new file/project.

Comment: @gardangerous no, not the design. Something is going on with your environment. How exactly are you running things?

Comment: @0x5453 First I indeed used ipykernel (apparently) in vscode. Now I tried to do it in a jupyter notebook and the problem is solved! Thanks a lot! But I'm really curious now what the reason might be? How did you know? Did this ever happened before to you? Is vscode/ipykernel not a good editor to write classes?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks! see post above^

Comment: VSCode is a fine editor. Something is going on with what you are doing, but we can only guess. The error message is showing different code than what you claim you are running, people have already guessed what *could* be the problem. Again, you have to explain *exactly* what you are doing or else people are just going to be guessing.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for your reply! I did not nothing else/more than I'm saying (at least not what of which I'm aware). The fact that the error message is showing something different is part of the issue (environment related), right? Sorry if my post is/was unclear. Anyways, thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: You haven't actually described what you are doing. You've merely said you are using VSCode, but you haven't described how you are actually running your code. To diagnose something like this you'd need to provide a lot of details.